# GitHub REST API to create Issues with creator parameter

Tags: node.js, git, api, rest, github

NodeJS APP: 
I try to create github issues from my nodeJS application using Github REST API "https://github.com/api/v3/repos/{owner}/{repo}/issues" with the following parameter and Token. I am passing the parameter "creator" to display who created/commented this issue. But it is displaying the owner of the gitHub Access token as the creator of the issue. How to fix this

```
request.post({
        url: githubApiEndpoint + "/repos/" + options.orgName + "/" + options.repoName + "/issues",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + options.accessToken
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            title: "creating issue",
            body: "description of issue",
            creator: "username",
            labels: ["question"]
        })
    }, callback);
```

Comment: the creator will be the authenticated user consuming the API.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue) you cannot. `creator` is no valid parameter. Besides that your example is syntactically incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. OAuth protocol aims to provide a way to do actions in the name of a specific user, the user who owns the token you get.

So, if you [create an issue](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/#create-an-issue), the author/creator will be the token owner. You cannot do actions in behalf of another person if you don't have his token